# Undo function not working on copy/paste action

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm currently making a financial template in Excel for our company (that still uses Excel 2010). As you guys probably know, you can change the same cell on multiple sheets by selecting multiple sheets. This is a handy feature, but it can really mess up your workbook if you do it accidentally.

So I'm trying to implement a feature that warns a user that makes a change while multiple sheets are selected, followed by a undo. It works great when you change a cell or when you change a cell by drag and drop, but it doesn't work when you copy and paste a cell. When I do this I get an error (translated from dutch) "Error 1004: method undo of object_Application has failed". What am I doing wrong?

The error:
[image]

My code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Sh.Name = Application.ActiveSheet.Name Then
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "WAARSCHUWING: Meerdere sheets geselecteerd! Veranderingen ongedaan gemaakt"
        Application.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        UndoLastAction

    End If
End If
End Sub

Sub UndoLastAction()
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Undo
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to get more than this method can do - `This method undoes only the last action taken by the user before running the macro, and it must be the first line in the macro. It cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands.` referer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.application.undo)

Comment: What do you mean with "You want to get more than this method can do?". You mean I can't undo a paste action?

How should I go about undoing a paste action?

Comment: I mean that this method doesn't support such action and provided with official information from Microsoft. Right now, without knowing neither your goal nor which conditions should be met, I have no idea how to achieve it. The idea that comes up is: if you can't undo an action - try to prevent it, but not sure whether it would work for you.

Comment: My goal is to restrict people from changing a sheet while multiple sheets(tabs?) are selected, to prevent people from messing the financial worksheet up. I could use the undo function in combination with preventing a copy/paste action, by disabling copy/paste when you select multiple sheets. But I can't seem to find such an event that fires when a sheet/tab is selected. Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I've used three event handlers at once:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' prevent Right-Click to paste something
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        ' check whether there is something in clipboard
        If Not Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
            MsgBox "WARNING: It is fobidden to do any actions on multiple sheets selection!"
            ' cancel the right-click action
            Cancel = True
            'ungroup sheets selection
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Item(Sh.Name).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ' prevent cell change if multiple sheets are selected
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "WARNING: It is fobidden to do any actions on multiple sheets selection!"
            'ungroup sheets selection
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Item(Sh.Name).Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ' prevent cell selection change if multiple sheets are selected
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "WARNING: It is fobidden to do any actions on multiple sheets selection!"
            'ungroup sheets selection
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Item(Sh.Name).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is what I've tried:
1.  Try to copy (Ctrl+C) text and select the target beforehand (same is without selecting target cell), then select multiple sheets and try to paste with Ctrl+V without changing selected cell – it will copy the value only to original sheet.
2.  Try to copy (Ctrl+C) text, then select multiple sheets and try to select the cell to paste
3.  Try to right-click with something in clipboard and multiple sheets selection.
[image]